# python to organize code to be more modular and generic

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have this loop that builds string out of some parameters,
I like to make it more modular in case other parameters are added
Currently cant find better idea from what i have now :

```
my_list = []
separator = "|"
for dd in data_:

    function_that_handle(dd)

    my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.myapp{separator}{self.container.app_type}'")
    my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.ip{separator}{self.container.server_ip}'")
    my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.port{separator}{self.container.server_port}'")
    my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.name{separator}{foo_prop.get('user_name')}'")
    my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.pass{separator}{self.container.org_password}'")
    my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.version{separator}{self.container.org_version}'")
    my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.uuid{separator}{self.container.app_uuid}'")
              

all_config=f"[{','.join(map(str, my_list))}]
```

The problem is that more parameters can be added so the list can be long.
Any idea to make it more organized?

Comment: What does `self.container..server_ip` do? Why are there two dots?

Comment: by mistake, the container is class  from other part of the app

Answer (score 1):

You could try to separate the static parts from the ones that change and put the latter into a `dict`:

```py
target_map = {'myapp': self.container.app_type,
              'ip': self.container.server_ip,
              'port': self.container.server_port,
              # etc.
             }

for dd in data_:
    for target, attr in target_map.items():
        my_list.append(f"'\${{{myapp}}}.{target}{separator}{attr}'")
```

Comment: ok this some kind of way to do it , what about eliminating the use of my_list?
i need it only for creating command delimited string

Comment: It's possible to get rid of `my_list`, but if you need to fill it with multiple elements from `data_`, I wouldn't really recommend it – you'd end up with a pretty ugly nested list comprehension. Maybe give it a better name like 'commands' instead of 'my_list'? And for `all_config`, you can just do `str(','.join(my_list))`, `my_list` contains only strings anyway, no need to stringify them again.